# Split string with inner and outer delimeters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split, delimiter

In my Javascript code, I have a string that is something like this:

```
"1943[15]43[67]12[32]"
```

I want to return an array like this:

```
["1","9","4","3","15","4","3","67","1", 2","32"]
```

That  is, I want it to separate every character, except the numbers inside the brackets, which I want to preserve as one element.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = '1943[15]43[67]12[32]',
    matches = str.match(/\d|\[\d+\]/g);

for (var i = 0, matchesLength = matches.length; i < matchesLength; i++) {
    matches[i] = matches[i].replace(/\D/g, '');
};

console.log(matches);
// ["1", "9", "4", "3", "15", "4", "3", "67", "1", "2", "32"]
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6LGj/).

Comment: No, you are not missing something, it was laziness on my part. I fixed it in an edit.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, hopefully this is elegant enough for you. :)

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you very much, it works. If I had enough rep to vote you up, I would.

Comment: @Peter You can always give me the big green tick :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "1943[15]43[67]12[32]", 
    re = new RegExp(/(\d)|\[(\d+)\]/g), 
    out = [],
    m;

while (m = re.exec(str)) { 
  out.push(m[2] || m[0]); 
}

console.log(out); // ["1", "9", "4", "3", "15", "4", "3", "67", "1", "2", "32"]
```

Comment: +1 I like this solution too. Any reason you didn't use `\d` for the second `|`?

Comment: Bad habits I suppose :) I've just fixed it.